# No apps in Windows default app setting for email

Tags: windows, windows-10, mailto

I would like to use Chrome as my default email app in Windows 10 LTSC 21H2 (19044). However, unlike any of the instructions I found on the internet, I can't even set Chrome as a default email app. It is just not present in the Windows settings in the "Email" section, although it does appear in the "Browser" section (no problems with that).

I have the mailto handler enabled and set as default in chrome://settings/handlers

**[image: Screenshot (stackExchange shows it as a link for some reason...)]**

Expected view:

**[image: Expected view (from the Internet)]**

Why there is no Browsers on my system, although I have Chrome, Edge and Firefox installed?

What should I do to fix this?

---

**Update 2023-08-26**
Today, I noticed that browsers have appeared in the Default Email App selection. **I didn't do anything**, so it seems like a Windows 10 bug which was fixed after one of the updates (despite the fact that Win10 is considered outdated and receives only security updates, as far as we know; furthermore, I use the LTSC version that has even fewer updates).
[image: Browsers are shown in the Default Email App selection menu]

Comment: Why  would you want chrome

Comment: Because I use Gmail.com as my default email interface

Comment: There are plenty instructions all over the internet, in which Chrome present in the list of email apps in Windows settings perfectly well. Updated question, screenshot added.

Comment: Can you add a link to a couple of the best instructions you have found?  I remember finding some kind of extension which assists in activating the gmail email handler in browsers, but I can't find the article now.

Comment: @JonGrah Unfortunately, I didn't save the instructions, and I can't find them quickly right now. Try google with "set Gmail as the default protocol handler for mail links"

Comment: I did.  I ended up installing Office which had Outlook.  But when I went to set default email app, then all the other options (including Brave browser) showed up magically.  Go figure

Answer (score 1):

An **email client** handles [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) messages, which are basically small **text** files passed from server to client. Some common email clients are free [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/), [Microsoft Mail](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/mail-and-calendar/9WZDNCRFHVQM), and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/mozilla-thunderbird/). One of these can be used as an email client.

GMail **website** is not a general-purpose email client (e.g, it won't display other mail providers, such as mail.com).

Chrome **browser** is not a general-purpose email client; it relies on the email URL to provide an interface.

Comment: Wrong. There are plenty instructions all over the internet, in which Chrome present in the list of email apps in Windows settings perfectly well. Updated question, screenshot added.